# Counting amount in Java loop

Tags: java

I am new in Java, I am learning for now. I want to create a small program that can sum up all my numbers which I show to my program. The main idea my program asks me for many numbers. This is the loop:

```
for (int k = 1; k <= 6 ; k++){
    System.out.println("Type " + k +". number");
    f = userInput.nextInt();
}
```

I wanted to know how my program can sum up all my numbers?

Comment: Use `f += userInput.nextInt();`. Be sure to check if there actually _is_ an `int` in the buffer, by using `if(userInput.hasNextInt())` before using `userInput.nextInt()`

Comment: Sounds like you want `sum` not `count`.

Comment: Good pracite is to begin loop with index 0 and end with expected value like: for(int i=0; i<6; i++). That mean 6 iteration (as in your code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare a variable to hold the sum:

```
int f, sum = 0;
for (int k = 1; k <= 6 ; k++){

    System.out.println("Type " + k +". number");
    f = userInput.nextInt();
    sum += f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use another variable to store the sum.

```
int sum = 0;

for (int k = 1; k <= 6; k++) {

    System.out.println("Type " + k +". number");

    f = userInput.nextInt();

    sum = sum + f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    int answer = 0;
    for (int k = 1; k <= 6 ; k++){

        System.out.println("Type " + k +". number");
        f = userInput.nextInt();
        answer += f; 

    }
    System.out.println(answer);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// assuming userInput is a Scanner

int sum = 0;

int f;

for (int k = 1; k <= 6 ; k++){

    System.out.println("Type " + k +". number");
    f = userInput.nextInt();

    sum += f;

}

// sum now holds the sum of all numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you did create a `scanner` object before this segment of code you can simply have a `sum` variable that hold the sum of your inputs.

```
       int sum =0;
       for (int k = 1; k <= 6 ; k++){

            System.out.println("Type " + k +". number");
            f = userInput.nextInt();
            sum += f;    
        }
```